# How can i hide my files and folders as they can be seen as "Index of /test/admin" on my server

Tags: html, .htaccess

[click here to see problem snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbubE.png)

this is the thing i want to hide from public, i tried everything on my server, my friend suggested me to use HotLink protection and it says it prevents other websites from directly linking to files (as specified below) on your website. Other sites will still be able to link to any file type that you don't specify below (ie. html files). i tried that but still it does not works.

i think i have to create .htacess file but i am not sure what should i type in that file so that my all website links are protected

Comment: are you using apache?

Comment: @HiteshMisro yes I am using apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also hide your files and folders from directory listing using directoryindex directive,

```
 DirectoryIndex /file.html
```

/file.html is the file you want to show instead of the directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

You're right you need to create a `.htaccess` file and copy the below code in it.

```
Options -Indexes
```

Hope this helps!